# Can not automatic mount external disk as writable

Tags: mount, filemanager, 22.04

I install Ubuntu 22..4 LTS but when click to external disk icon on file manager ask me the password (luks) and mount disk, but the filesystem is read only.

In 20.04 LTS works fine but 22.04 is read only.

How to fix automatic mount disk from file manager?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your drives mount correctly as expected, make sure the file system is healthy. A file system must be "clean" before Linux will mount it with read and write permissions.

Quite likely from what you are telling, the drive is accessible in MS Windows as well and is formatted with the ntfs file system of MS Windows. Only MS Windows is fully equipped to check and eventually repair that proprietary file system.

- Connect the drive to a Windows system.
- Check and repair the drive using the Windows file system check tool. See the user manual of your Windows system if you are not sure how to find it. This will check and eventually repair issues with the file system, and mark it "clean".
- Properly unmount the drive from the Windows, i.e. using the tray icon to remove devices.
- Now, the drive will mount correctly under Linux.

To prevent this from happening in the future, always correctly remove a drive, using the tray icon in Windows, or using "Safely remove drives" in Files (right-click menu of the drive in the left bar). Alternatively, shut the system fully down before unplugging the drive. **For Windows, that requires the fast start feature to be disabled**. With the "fast start" feature, Windows does not close files/drives before turning off as one of the tricks to allow to restart faster.